# Is this the correct code to track AJAX form submission in Google Analytics?

Tags: forms, events, google-analytics

I would like to track everytime a visitor clicks an AJAX contact form's submit button. I created an event in Google Analytics and plan to add some javascript to the submit button code.

This is the current submit button code:

```
<button class="button" title="Send" type="submit"><span><span>Send</span></span></button>
```

This is how the code will look after I add the category, action, etc.:

```
<button class="button" title="Send" type="submit" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'Inquiry', 'Inquiry Form', 0, false]);"><span><span>Send</span></span></button>
```

Is this correct? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Update - here's the javascript where I see some kind of form validation. As suggested by Crayon Violent I'd like to avoid tracking failed form submits. Now the question is where do I add the Google Analytics code so I can track only successful form submisions? Note: to protect site owner's privacy I replaced the domain/brand with "XXXXXX", also you'll note there's reference to 2 forms, one is a contact form and the other is a form for job seekers to send their CV. Well yes, I know it's a bit messy to include both forms on the same page, visible at the same time, may confuse users but that bit does not depend on me :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
var contactFormCv = new VarienForm('contactFormCv', true);

jQuery(function(){

jQuery('#contactForm input, #contactForm textarea').each(function(){
jQuery(this).focus(function(){
jQuery(this).css({'background-position': '1000px 1000px'});
}).blur(function(){
if(jQuery(this).val() == ''){
jQuery(this).css({'background-position': '5px 9px'});
            }
});
});

jQuery('#contactForm').submit(function(){

jQuery('.form-column .message', form).remove();

var form = jQuery(this);
var message = jQuery('<div class="message"></div>');

jQuery('.form-column', form).append(message);

if(contactForm.validator.validate()){

jQuery(message).html('<img                  src="http://www.XXXXXX.com/skin/frontend/np/XXXXXX/images/XXXXXX/sending-contact.gif" />');

            var data = '';
            jQuery('input, select, textarea', this).each(function(){
                var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
                var val = jQuery(this).val();

                data = data+name+'='+val+'&';

            });

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data == 'true'){
                        jQuery('input, select, textarea', form).val('').css({'background-position': '5px 9px'});
                        jQuery(message).html('Mensaje enviado.');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    var iframe = jQuery('<iframe></iframe>').attr({id: 'uploadcv', name: 'uploadcv', scrolling: 'none', frameborder: 0}).addClass('uploadcv').css({height: 0, width: 0, border: 0, display: 'none'});
    jQuery('#contactFormCv').attr({target: 'uploadcv'}).submit(function(){

        var form = jQuery(this);
        var message = jQuery('<div class="message"></div>');

        form.after().append(message);

        if(contactFormCv.validator.validate()){
            jQuery(message).html('<img src="http://www.XXXXXX.com/skin/frontend/np/XXXXXX/images/XXXXXX/sending-contact.gif" />');
            iframe.load(function(){
                jQuery('input, select', form).val('');
                jQuery(message).html('Mensaje enviado.');
            });
        }

    }).after().append(iframe);

});
```

//]]>

Comment: Did it work? Did you run into any issues?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. I will be sending this to a dev who'll do the implementation, but before I send it I want to make sure it's the right code to avoid going back and forth. In a nutshell, I don't want to complicate de dev's life :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you have the base on-page GA code, that should "work," But here is something to consider about the behavior of where you currently have it...that code is going to trigger every time that button is pushed.  So if you have form validation (whether server-side or client-side), and the visitor fails to fill out the form properly and gets an error message...well you just tracked a failed form submit.  Now let's say the visitor tries again and fails again.  Now you have 2 hits.  3rd time's a charm and he gets it right and the form is successfully submitted and you now have 3 hits showing up in GA, and you have no idea how many of those hits were successful or not.  If you don't care about this, then you're good to go.

But as a best practice, most people implement the tracking to either trigger a different value to breakdown whether success or fail, or else only track on successful form submissions. So if you have javascript form validation on your page to make sure the fields are filled out correctly, you should really be placing that GA code within your validation code, after it has passed validation.  Alternatively, if the form validation code is server-side, you should instead output the code with whatever "thank you" dialogue is returned.

edited to respond to your posted code:

Can't be 100% without full page context or testing, but it looks like you would want to put it here:

```
success: function(data){
  if(data == 'true'){
    jQuery('input, select, textarea', form).val('').css({'background-position': '5px 9px'});
    jQuery(message).html('Mensaje enviado.');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'Inquiry', 'Inquiry Form', 0, false]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Crayon, thanks a lot for taking the time to reply. I totally agree with you. I checked the code and the only validation I found is within the script lines. I'll edit my question and will post the AJAX code. It'd be great if you or someone else would let me know where to place the GA code. Again, thanks for your valuable help. –

Comment: I edited my answer to include my suggestion.  Though honestly, if your web dev doesn't know what to do, maybe you should spend your money on someone else!

Comment: Crayon: Thanks for your help. To cut a long story short, I have to make do with what's available, I'm not the decision maker.